# NSTextView -(void) setMarkedTextAttributes: method how to set which text is marked?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstextview, nsrange

NSTextView has a

```
-(void)setMarkedTextAttributes:
```

method.

But can I mark text NSRanges programmatically ? can I mark text the same way as I can select NSRanges ?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, You can mark the text with specific range using the API 
  `- (void)setMarkedText:(id)aString
        selectedRange:(NSRange)selRange` 
  For more reference you check this apple doc : [NSTextInput Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Protocols/NSTextInput_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTextInput/setMarkedText:selectedRange:)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however, this lacks the chance to select more than one NSRange like I would like to do.